# Stand heavy mirror on its corner

Tags: hanging, mirror

I have a heavy square mirror and a shoe bench. I would like to put the mirror on top of the bench, but  the mirror on top, but standing on its corner.

The mirror is too heavy to hang from the wall.
I can put a nail on the wall and attach the top corner of the mirror to it.
This will make the mirror not move sideways.

Now, for the corner of the mirror that would be resting on the shoe bench I would like to make something that lies between the mirror and the bench.
That it serves as extra support but also prevents the mirror and the bench from damaging each other. They are both made out of wood.

I am not sure what would be a good shape or material for such a stand.

I was surprised I didn't have much luck finding images in Google with a mirror standing on its corner. It seems a more uncommon setting than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

> The mirror is too heavy to hang from the wall.

No, its not.  You can hang 300+ lbs on a wall.  Find the center line of a stud and use the proper fastener.

Even without a stud, a couple high quality dry wall anchors would hold up 50 lbs easily.

> It seems a more uncommon setting than I thought.

Because it's a good way to break the mirror.

Comment: I hanged it from the wall but broke the anchors out of the wall and it fell. Miraculously it didn't brake. That it why I am trying an alternative to hanging.

Comment: @Hellen I'm gong to guess you probably used the wrong kind of anchors. Can you edit your question to show what you used and how they failed to work?